# Failing to open rails console and run a script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I'm trying to open a Rails console and run a ruby script in it. The script works fine till the rails console opens and then nothing happens. Only when I exit the console manually, do I get an error message saying:

```
-bash: load: command not found
```

These are the commands I'm using:

```
source /etc/profile
source /etc/default/<my-app>
cd /usr/share/<my-app>
NO_AUTH=Y bundle exec ruby-flo -S rails console
load '/home/sirish.aditya/test_code.rb'
```

How do I load the script into the console?

Comment: Do you need to execute this ruby script when you open your shell or you need to run this script after running the rails console? Moreover, do you need to run this script with rails application or standalone ruby interpreter?

Comment: I am trying to set up a cron to invoke a particular method in my rails app. For that, I'm trying to load the entire code into the rails console and then invoke the method from the script, so that I can schedule it.

Comment: Why don't you try [rails runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) for the same.  Or you could use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem as well.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks a lot for your help @RohitJangid

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
echo "$(ruby /home/sirish.aditya/test_code.rb)"
```

As per you requirement, you could even try [rails runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) or [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

Comment: Hi Rohit,

Even when I do as you suggest, the program's not being loaded. Only on exit am I seeing the message:

Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.21)
irb(main):001:0> exit
In test_code.rb - test_code is running

Comment: @SirishAditya Don't forget to remove that `load` command. Also source this changes to your running shell or restart your shell.

Comment: Yes, I did that. This is my source.rb now:
`code`
source /etc/profile
source /etc/default/fk-supplier-portal
source /home/sirish.aditya/test_code.rb
cd /usr/share/fk-supplier-portal
NO_AUTH=Y bundle exec ruby-flo -S rails console
echo "$(ruby /home/sirish.aditya/test_code.rb)"
`code`
And test_code.rb is 
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts "in test code- test_code is running"

But still my output is:

Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.21)
irb(main):001:0> exit
in test code- test_code is running

Comment: @SirishAditya You could also try and write this command in `irbrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. As soon as the `rails console` is invoked either manually or through a `bash script`, you are essentially running a separate process which has no visibility into the subsequent statements (ex: load).

When you quit the `rails console` then the process of execution comes back to the main process (which is `bash`) which does not have any idea what `load` means and is failing.

You should either use [`rails runner`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) or custom [`rake task`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
cd /usr/share/<my-app>; source /etc/default/<my-app>; 
cat ~/test_code.rb  | NO_AUTH=Y bundle exec ruby-flo -S rails console
```